# How to avoid RichTextBox Growing?

Tags: c#, winforms

how to avoid richtextbox growing more than the fixed size
on pasting a text in c#. I am trying to create a windows page like structure using the help multiple richtextboxes.

Program take the page setting at the start of the application.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: Why is it growing?  Only programmers grow automatically, happens when they eat too much junk food.  Set the MaximumSize property, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `MaxLenght` property for your `RichTextBox` and you will be able to do what you are trying. I do not know what is the "fixed" size that you wanna give to the control, so you´ll have to try with your values:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.maxlength(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes i can count number of characters, that can accommodate inside the bound of the fixed size richtextbox, and set the maxlength property to the same size but it only work on plain text, I am working on formatted text. if user change the font size of some text, so the number of character will be different.

I just want to count the number of characters that can accommodate inside the fixed size richtextbox. and those characters are formatted text.